# ASP.NET Core Dropzone issues

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I am trying to upload files using Dropzone and an ASP.Net core Site. The code goes with no errors and takes me to the successful page, so I am lost as to what to do. My code is below:
HTML:

```
            <form id="newNotice" class="newNotice" method="post" action="https://localhost:5003/api/Attach" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input class="fill-width input" type="text" id="newposttitle" placeholder="Title" required />
                <select id="Cat" class="fill-width input">
                    <option value="">Select what Category this KB article applies to</option>
                    <option value="0">SIMS.Net</option>
                    <option value="1">SEN</option>
                    <option value="2">PC & On-site Services</option>
                    <option value="3">Office 365</option>
                    <option value="4">OneDrive & SharePoint</option>
                    <option value="5">IT Support</option>
                </select>
                <textarea id="details" class="fill-width" placeholder="Full Details" style="height: 100%;"></textarea>
                <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
                    <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" style="width: 100%;" value="Save" class="fill-width" onclick="validate()">
            </form>
```

JS:

```
            Dropzone.options.dropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

                // The configuration we've talked about above
                url: "#",
                autoProcessQueue: false,
                uploadMultiple: false,
                parallelUploads: 100,
                maxFiles: 100,
                paramName: "files",
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                // The setting up of the dropzone
                init: function () {
                    var myDropzone = this;
                }
            }
```

Below JS is used to process the queue:

```
                            var myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement(".dropzone");
                            myDropzone.processQueue();
```

ASP:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Attach([FromForm]IList<IFormFile> files)
        {
            try
            {
                string absolutepath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                Path.Combine(absolutepath, "Attachments");

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var uploads = Path.Combine(absolutepath, file.FileName);
                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(uploads, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                        }
                        
                    } catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("~/results.html");

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //  return BadRequest(new { success = false, message = "Error file failed to upload" });
                return BadRequest(exception.Message);
            }
        }
```

I am completely lost as to why this does not work. I get no obvious errors as to what may be happening
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Further to this, it seems Dropzone is not passing the files to my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the dropzone will auto Discover the form element or dropzone related element to generate the dropzone div.

Since your form action has set the action value and the Dropzone.options has also set the url, that means it will throw a error that `No URL provided` error.

Since I don't know what is your actually requirement. If you don't want to use form action url, you could set it in the Dropzone.options url attribute and disable the `autoDiscover` attribute.

More details ,you could refer to below example:

```
<form id="newNotice" class="newNotice" method="post" action="https://localhost:44350/api/Attach" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="fill-width input" type="text" id="newposttitle" placeholder="Title" required />
    <select id="Cat" class="fill-width input">
        <option value="">Select what Category this KB article applies to</option>
        <option value="0">SIMS.Net</option>
        <option value="1">SEN</option>
        <option value="2">PC & On-site Services</option>
        <option value="3">Office 365</option>
        <option value="4">OneDrive & SharePoint</option>
        <option value="5">IT Support</option>
    </select>
    <textarea id="details" class="fill-width" placeholder="Full Details" style="height: 100%;"></textarea>
    <div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
        <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" style="width: 100%;" value="Upload" class="fill-width" onclick="upload()">
    <input type="submit" style="width: 100%;" value="Save" class="fill-width" onclick="validate()">



</form>

<script>
    Dropzone.options.dropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

        // The configuration we've talked about above
        url: "https://localhost:44350/api/Attach",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: false,
        autoDiscover : false,
        parallelUploads: 100,
        maxFiles: 100,
        paramName: "files",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        // The setting up of the dropzone
        init: function () {
            var myDropzone = this;
        }
    }
  

    function upload() {
        var myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement(".dropzone");
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    }
</script>
```

Notice: I add a new button to fire the processQueue method.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Adding the URL to dropzone and removing the one from the form did the trick. Thank you!